# How can I pass the same data to different threads without copying it?

Tags: multithreading, rust

Struct `S` may be actually some big data, for example a large `Vec`. If I have one thread and do not use the data after creating a thread, I can move data to it, but with two threads (or using the same data in main thread), it is impossible.

```
struct S {
    i : i32,
}

fn thr(s : &S)
{
}

fn main()
{
    let s1 = S { i:1 };
    thr(&s1);
    let t1 = std::thread::spawn(|| thr(&s1)); // does not work
    let t2 = std::thread::spawn(|| thr(&s1)); // does not work
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I'd **highly** recommend reading [*The Rust Programming Language*](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book), specifically the [chapter on concurrency](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/concurrency.html). In it, you are introduced to [`Arc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/sync/struct.Arc.html):

```
use std::sync::Arc;

struct S {
    i: i32,
}

fn thr(s: &S) {}

fn main() {
    let s1 = Arc::new(S { i: 1 });
    thr(&s1);

    let s2 = s1.clone();
    let t2 = std::thread::spawn(move || thr(&s2));

    let s3 = s1.clone();
    let t3 = std::thread::spawn(move || thr(&s3));

    t2.join();
    t3.join();
}
```

Notably, when `Arc`s are cloned, they simply bump a reference count, not duplicate the contained data.

Comment: This works, but this forces me to use atomic counter and, more important, this requires changing type of variable in many places (functions' signatures). In real program variable s1 is created in one place, then it is passed through several function calls before it is passed to thread functions.

Comment: @GennadyProskurin, because all threads are independent, there is simply no way to avoid `Arc`. The data has to be stored somewhere (i.e. someone has to own the data). Because threads are independent, it can't be owned by anyone of them - it would be possible then for this data to be destroyed while other threads still have a handle to it. If threads are [scoped](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/thread/fn.scoped.html), then this restriction could be lifted, but `scoped` API is unstable for an important [reason](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/24385).

Comment: @GennadyProskurin in addition to Vladimir's usual spot-on advice, I can only offer the suggestion to create your own struct that wraps and hides the `Arc` and `S` structs. Then you can pass that struct around, and changes like this are less disruptive, as you've separated concerns a bit.

Answer (score 0):

If this is C or C++ the allocated memory won't go away until its explicitly freed, and also, unless the objects are declared threadlocal then all threads in your app can refer to them.

In the code you wrote it seems your structure is on the stack rather than the heap, so once it goes out of scope that object pointer is invalid.

The brutal way to deal with this, without ARC, is to simply allocate the object and the pass the allocated pointer to your threads. Some thread needs to be the one to ultimately delete it (that's where ARC is a good idea).

Comment: "*If this is C or C++*" but it isn't... it's Rust. Did you mean to draw an analogy to C / C++? If so, I don't get it ^_^